# Return response multiline

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

```
import sys
import logging
import rds_config
import pymysql
#rds settings
rds_host  = "xxxxxx"
name = rds_config.db_username
password = rds_config.db_password
db_name = rds_config.db_name

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5)
except:
    logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySQL instance.")
    sys.exit()

logger.info("SUCCESS: Connection to RDS MySQL instance succeeded")
def handler(event, context):
    """
    This function fetches content from MySQL RDS instance
    """

    data = ''

    with conn.cursor() as cur:

        cur.execute("Select * from xxxxx where Status = 'Active';")

        for row in cur:
            logger.info(row)

            data+= " ".join(map(str, row)) + "\n"


        return data
```

I am getting the response as below

```
Response:
"1 xxxxxxx Full Active 2019-12-31\n2 yyyyyyyy Full Active 2019-12-31\n"
```

I want it as below (is without quotes possible?)

```
Response:
"1 xxxxxxx Full Active 2019-12-31"
"2 yyyyyyyy Full Active 2019-12-31"
```

Python newbie. Can anyone please help ?

Comment: return in list and element corresponds to text u want

Comment: data=[], data.append(row), return data

Comment: I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for response. Well print(data) shows fine ... but I am calling this code through API gateway in AWS and using Postman it doesn't return in multi line format

Comment: @prashantrana doing that gives me the below error

Comment: Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to marshal response: datetime.date(2019, 12, 31) is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "Runtime.MarshalError"
}

Comment: Added screenshot to show what I am seeing in Postman

Comment: instead of that keep your orignal code and `return {'data':data}`

Answer (score 2):

```
"1 xxxxxxx Full Active 2019-12-31\n2 yyyyyyyy Full Active 2019-12-31\n"
```

is a Python representation of the string

```
1 xxxxxxx Full Active 2019-12-31
2 yyyyyyyy Full Active 2019-12-31
```

There is nothing to do: you already have a multi-line string; try `print(data)` to see.

Comment: Well print(data) shows fine yes ... but I am calling this code through API gateway in AWS and using Postman it doesn't return in multi line format

Comment: Then you're showing us the wrong code, no? If you know this code is working correctly, why are you showing it to us?

Comment: code is working. Thats not an issue ... I am showing code because maybe you will understand what i am trying to do and offer any suggestions..

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. It's like coming to a doctor's office complaining that your _leg_ hurts, and giving an X-ray of your _arm_, saying "I know it's healthy, but I hoped you would understand". We have no idea what your API gateway does, or how `handler` is invoked.

Comment: OK is there a way to return print(data) because print(data) outputs in a format I want ... so I want the value I am returning to also be in the same format

Comment: You _are_ returning the value in the same format. If something is wrong, it is not wrong _here_. I don't know how else to say it.